# How can i center the list items inside my unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I have this: 
 **HTML:**

```
   <body> 
    <header>
        <div class="cont">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>BUY</li>
                <LI>CONTACT</LI>
                <LI>MORE</LI>
                <div class="clear">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header> 
   </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.cont{
    width: 60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.cont ul{
list-style: none;
background: red;
}

.cont ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding:1em;
    background: green;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zggjx7uu/

i want to know how i can get the green blocks to get in the middle of the red 
container. i know this maybe newbie but i have been having issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zggjx7uu/3/

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="cont">
        <ul>
            <li>HOME</li><li>BUY</li><li>CONTACT</li><li>MORE</li>
            <div class="clear">
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Notice that the `li`s must be written on the same line because `inline-block` elements keep their whitespace, to eliminate that whitespace you either have to write the `li` on the same line or use a negative `margin`.

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.cont{
    width: 60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.cont ul{
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.cont ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:1em;
    background: green;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Like the prevoius answer, you are right, and also you helped me get rid of the white spaces. So why does the white spaces are there? like wtf?

Comment: The whitespaces are there because inline elements (and thus also inline-block) elements inherently preserve whitespace. If you place them next to each other in the HTML-document you don't need the negative margin @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: Really weired... but hey! it works so thank you. Got to wait three minutes to accept your answer

Comment: @kolsyrad not the best way for putting all your elements in one line.

Comment: you can omit the closing </li> tags if you want to keep the structure but I dont think this is a very good practice, otherwise you can use comments between the lis to simulate the lack of whitespace

Comment: Just a question, is it a way to center floated list? Thanks

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai i saw your JSFiddle, thats another spectacular way of getting rid of the white spaces, god i love this community, Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block` for your child elements and apply `text-align:center` for your parent element.

Next for removing white spaces, apply `font-size:0` for your parent element then apply what ever size you want for your child elements.

```
 .cont ul{
 list-style: none;
 background: red;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:0;
 }

.cont ul li{
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
padding:1em;
font-size:14px;
background: green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zggjx7uu/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align: center;` on your ul and `display: inline-block` on the li's.

```
.cont ul{
list-style: none;
background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.cont ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:1em;
    background: green;
}
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/zggjx7uu/2/

Comment: It does work, but it get some strange white space between the green list items. how to get rid of it? margin:0; wont work.

Comment: see my answer, you cant have space between the lis

Comment: Set the font-size of the ul to 0, and set it back on the li. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/zggjx7uu/4/

Answer (score 1):

use `display: inline-block;` instead `float: left`

parent- `text-align: center;`

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: lightgrey;
}

.cont{
 width: 60%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.cont ul{
list-style: none;
background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.cont ul li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:1em;
 background: green;
}

.clear{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="cont">
  <ul>
   <li>HOME</li><!--
   --><li>BUY</li><!--
   --><li>CONTACT</li><!--
   --><li>MORE</li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.cont{
    width: 60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: red;
}

.cont ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: green;
}
```